# I want responsive image gallery that I can scroll horizontally. Only with pure HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css

I managed to do this.

BUT I need at the end of this image gallery to have two links.

Right after last image in the middle of the screen I need to have (next, info) links.

please help, thanks.

I dont want any javascript. I tried everything but the text I cannot make to be where i want to.

```css
html, body{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: "minion-pro", serif !important;

}
#wrapper {

height: 100%;

}

html, body, ul, li{

  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;

  text-decoration:none;

}

ul{

  width:100%;
  height:100%; /* CHANGE */

  overflow-y:inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: large;

}

ul li{

  display:inline;

  height:100%;

}

ul li{

  max-height:100%;
  height:100%; /* CHANGE */
  width:auto !important; /* CHANGE */

}

img{
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  max-height:1000px;
  height:80%; /* CHANGE */
  width:auto !important; /* CHANGE */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
 
<div id="wrapper">
 

<ul>
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 5%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/01.jpg"/>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 5%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/02.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 5%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/03.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 5%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/04.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 5%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/05.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 5%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/06.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img style="padding-right: 20%;" src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/07.jpg"/>
  </li>
  
  
  
 </ul> 
 </div> 


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a copy of yours having links in the end.

I changed the `ul`/`li` to `display: table`/`display: table-cell`.

```css
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: "minion-pro", serif !important;

}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body, ul, li{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; /* CHANGE */
  overflow-y:inherit;
  font-size: large;
}

ul li{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* CHANGE */
  width:auto !important; /* CHANGE */
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  max-height:1000px;
  height:80vh; /* CHANGE */
  width:auto !important; /* CHANGE */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <ul>
    
    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/01.jpg"/>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/02.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/03.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/04.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/05.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/06.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/07.jpg"/>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="">some link 1</a><br>
      <a href="">some link 2</a>

    </li>

  </ul> 
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Css only](https://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/mVgKEP) Here
`CSS Only`

```css
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/01.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/02.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/03.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/04.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/05.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/06.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/07.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
</div>
```

You can also use **Unslider** http://unslider.com/ it's pretty awesome.

Comment: @Filip Kartousek I made you the slider here !!

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox:

html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/01.jpg"/>
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/02.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/03.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img  src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/04.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img  src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/05.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img  src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/06.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img  src="http://filipkartousek.com/new/Barum/07.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    whatever
  </li>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}

ul li img {
        height: 90vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3da/go3zL4eq/)